# Node js 404 not found 'localhost:3000/register/'

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Hi im new with nodejs and express, and im struggling with documentation a routing with this framework.
I created a route but when i run the project with its URL i have the typicall error, 404 not found.

routes/register.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


//REGISTRO

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('register')
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var registerRouter = require('./routes/register');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/register', registerRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

im not used to this framework. I usually use laravel or django but routing and using views it seems to be very different.

Answer (score 1):

you've registered the route under `/register/register` express is saying that when you hit the register route then load the registerRouter which then doesn't have a `/` path just another `/register`. So it will concatenate the 2 paths to `/register/register`.

either remove the url from the use method

```
app.use(registerRouter);
```

or change routes.register to

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


//REGISTRO

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('register')
});

module.exports = router;
```